# Tailing an awked log

Tags: logging, awk

This is what bothers me:

I have a log file, written in a specific format, such as:

```
[DEBUG    7] 2012-06-12 09:26:37.847 [MOD: UNK/0 ] [FILE:ModuleManager.cpp:541] [FUNC: ModuleManager::handleStatusRequestMessage] [MSG:Got request for unsupported ALLOCATION_STATUS ]
```

so the blocks are pretty well separated. I am viewing this log through a tail, on a 80x25 terminal screen and it looks horrible (no, I cannot change the screen, it's an embedded device).

Can you help me in creating a tail/awk (or similar) combination to achieve something like:

```
2012-06-12 09:26:37.847 Got request for unsupported ALLOCATION_STATUS
```

or

```
2012-06-12 09:26:37.847 ModuleManager::handleStatusRequestMessage - Got request for unsupported ALLOCATION_STATUS
```

or

```
2012-06-12 09:26:37.847 ModuleManager.cpp:541 ModuleManager::handleStatusRequestMessage - Got request for unsupported ALLOCATION_STATUS
```

from the long line above?

Thanks

Comment: Do not change your screen.  Instead become an advocate for 80 column text!  Output, logs, source code--all under 80 columns.  Tell your friends; it's not just a relic from the 70s.  It's a great idea for the future as well as the past!

Comment: @WilliamPursell: Two words: "big monitors".

Comment: @Dennis Big monitors on which I can display 6-8 files side by side--unless one of them uses 120 columns per line!

Comment: @Dennis Four words: "Bad eyes, big fonts"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk -F '[][]' '{print $3, $10}' logfile
2012-06-12 09:26:37.847  MSG:Got request for unsupported ALLOCATION_STATUS
$ awk -F '[][]' '{print $3, $8, $10}' logfile
 2012-06-12 09:26:37.847  FUNC: ModuleManager::handleStatusRequestMessage MSG:Got request for unsupported ALLOCATION_STATUS
$ awk -F '[][]' '{print $3, $6, $8, $10}' logfile
 2012-06-12 09:26:37.847  FILE:ModuleManager.cpp:541 FUNC: ModuleManager::handleStatusRequestMessage MSG:Got request for unsupported ALLOCATION_STATUS
```

or

```
$ awk -F '[][]|MOD:|FUNC:|FILE:|MSG:' '{print $3, $8, $11 " - " $14}' inputfile
2012-06-12 09:26:37.847  ModuleManager.cpp:541  ModuleManager::handleStatusRequestMessage - Got request for unsupported ALLOCATION_STATUS
```

Comment: combined with tail it's perfect: `tail -f log.txt | awk -F '[][]' '{print $3, $10}'`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest `sed` for a radical format wipe out:

```
tailf -f logfile | sed -e 's/\[MSG:\([^]]*\)\]/\1/' -e 's/\[[^]]*\] *//g'
```